# Deactivate Return-Value-Assignment to a Function in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, function

Is there a way to deactivate the following behavior of the IDE?
This is very silly and you don't see this error at once. Hopy my comments in the coding explain it well.

As you see both lines return different things:

*Faulty Line (Returns "false" because it addresses the return value of the function I am in)*

```
If HasIpAddress Then
```

*Correct Line (Adresses the function with an other signature):*

```
If HasIpAddress() Then
```

Coding:

```
Public Shared Function HasIpAddress(ByVal p_WaitTimeInSeconds As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim dEnd As Date = Date.Now.AddSeconds(p_WaitTimeInSeconds)

    While dEnd > Date.Now

        If HasIpAddress Then ' THIS is the faulty line. 
        ' If HasIpAddress() Then ' THIS line would work, because of the "()"
        ' it addresses the function without parameters and not 
        ' the return-value of the current function I am in.
            Return True
        End If

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

    End While

    Return False

End Function

Public Shared Function HasIpAddress() As Boolean

     With System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(NetworkTools.GetMyIpAddress())
           ...Check for Loopbacks, Any, None etc...
     End While

     Return True

End Function
```

Comment: This isn't the IDE - this is the *language*.

Comment: Don't you consider of giving different names to your two functions?

Comment: Yeah I could rename that function, but this problem can occure any time again. Because of that I wanted to ask If this assignement can be deactivated somehow. Visual Studio has some Options to enable restrictions, so mabye also for this.

Comment: @Ian I’m generally a fan of avoiding overloading when the functions perform different purposes. But here it’s really the same function, and should have the same name.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I see, I am not a fan of overloading too, but I probably miss the part which you mention as "really the same function". I am thinking of giving name like `HasIpAddressBase` or so.

Comment: @Ian Well logically speaking this is *one function*, with an optional argument for the timeout; it’s just that it’s easier to implement (but this is strictly an *implementation detail and shouldn’t affect the public interface) as two separate functions rather than one function with optional argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change this behaviour, it’s a non-configurable part of the language (unlike, say, `Option Strict`). So there’s no general way for avoiding this pitfall other than training yourself to *always* put `()` behind function calls, even if the function has no argument, and hoping that muscle memory will kick in at some point.